# date variables in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Complete beginner to bash scripts, please forgive probably a simple question:

I have this

```
#!/bin/bash
python copycalls.py /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/2015/07/29
```

This does what I need, but I want to replace the last 3 bits with the current year/month/day

Something like this

python copycalls.py /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/YEAR/MONTH/DAY

Are those available as variables I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this by appending the `date` command to the end of your string:

```
#!/bin/bash
python copycalls.py /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/$(date +"%Y/%m/%d")
```

You can read more about using `date` on [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/timedate.html) page

Answer (score 0):

You can use date cmd

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/$(date +%Y/%m/%d)"

echo "$path"
```

Answer (score 0):

With a sufficiently recent version of `bash` (4.2?), you can use `printf` to avoid a call to `date`:

```
printf -v path '/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/%(%Y/%m/%d)T'
python copycalls.py "$path"
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use `date`

```
python copycalls.py "$(date +"/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/%Y/%m/%d")"
```

(which is the same as the other answers; I just crammed more into the format string.)